# Php, Jquery/JS, Submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Okay, so for some reason I have a crazy problem that is just making my mind go crazy. I have an open source shoutbox, worked great in the `website.com/shouot/SHOUTDIREC/chat.html` but once I try to embed into my previous built site(`website.com/chat.php`), the submit button like grays out and I can't submit the post. Another thing is it doesn't show previous post that show up when I go back to `SHOUTDIREC/chat.html`. I tried changing `/chat.php` to `/chat.html` nothing. Still grayed out not working submit button.

This is the `./chat.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <title>Making a Shoutbox with PHP and jQuery</title>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/assets/css/emojione.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./shout/assets/css/styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./livechat/php/app.php?widget-init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>     
    <div class="shoutbox">            
        <h1>Shout box <img src='./shout/assets/img/refresh.png'/></h1>            
        <ul class="shoutbox-content"></ul>            
        <div class="shoutbox-form">
            <h2>Write a message <span>×</span></h2>                
            <form action="./shout/publish.php" method="post">
                <label for="shoutbox-name">nickname </label> <input type="text" id="shoutbox-name" name="name"/>
                <label class="shoutbox-comment-label" for="shoutbox-comment">message </label> <textarea id="shoutbox-comment" name="comment" maxlength='240'></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Shout!"/>
            </form>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <!-- Include jQuery and the EmojiOne library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./shout/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Here is the `/SHOUTDIREC/chat.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <title>Wyfi-Chat</title>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/assets/css/emojione.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css" />
</head>    
<body>     
    <div class="shoutbox">            
        <h1>Shout box <img src='./assets/img/refresh.png'/></h1>            
        <ul class="shoutbox-content"></ul>            
        <div class="shoutbox-form">
            <h2>Write a message <span>×</span></h2>                
            <form action="./publish.php" method="post">
                <label for="shoutbox-name">nickname </label> <input type="text" id="shoutbox-name" name="name"/>
                <label class="shoutbox-comment-label" for="shoutbox-comment">message </label> <textarea id="shoutbox-comment" name="comment" maxlength='240'></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Shout!"/>
            </form>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <!-- Include jQuery and the EmojiOne library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

I don't know why it's not working. Maybe a permission issue? Or what? I have no clue, and my mind is going absolutely nuts.

Comment: Do you have a demo?

Comment: license problem? Since you're using an external library.

Comment: It was working at first though Mouser.

Comment: http://www.wyfi-stresser.com/shout/

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function AjaxShowForm(a, v) {
        var data = $("#" + v).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/45403161?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (html) { // this happens before actual call
                $("#" + a).html("<img src='//vistablog.ir/images/loading_.gif'></img>loading..");
                $("#" + a).show();
            },
            success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
                $("#" + a).html("");
                $("#" + a).show();
                $("#" + a).append(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='' method='post' id='form1'>
    <table dir='rtl' border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>name <span style="color:red">*</span></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in1' required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>description</td>
            <td><textarea name='in3'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>family</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in2'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='in4'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>roles</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='in5'></td>
        </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' value='submit' onclick='return AjaxShowForm("showajax1","form1")'></td>
    </table>
    <p id='showajax1'></p></form>
</center>
```